# Javascript function does not execute on page load but executes when called from Console Window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a javascript function to append options on a select input field.
Below is code snippet:

```
function loadZoneDropDown(){
    var datas = placesZoneData.zones, a = document.getElementById("route_start_point");
    for(let t in datas){
        var value_data = datas[t];
            $('#route_start_point').append('<option value="'+t+'">'+value_data.data["name"]+'</option>');
        
    }
    sortSelectList(a);
}
```

This function is called inside a `load()` function on the `<body>` tag as below:

```
function load(){
   //otherFunctions();
    loadZoneDropDown();
}
```

HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body onload="load()">
  </body>
</html>
```

The page loads and No new option is appended to the `#route_start_point` select field. When I run the same function directly on console, the script executes and the options are populated.
Can you help me figure the problem out.
Note that `otherFunctions()` are running very OK and fine on the webpage.
[image: Screenshot of code before console run]

Screenshot after console execution of loadZoneDropDown() below:
[image: After function execution on console]

Comment: May  placesZoneData.zones is empty on page load, did you check it?

Comment: placesZoneData.zones have data loaded on page load, see snippet below: 

`{386: {…}}
386:
data: {group_id: '0', name: 'New zone 1', color: '#FF0000', visible: 'true', name_visible: 'true', …}
label_layer: e {options: {…}, _source: undefined, _initHooksCalled: true, _latlng: o.LatLng, _content: 'New zone 1', …}`

Comment: What indication do you have that `loadZoneDropDown` isn't executed on page load? `for( let t in undefined) {...}` won't throw an error - but won't produce any option elements either. I suggest checking that `placesZoneData.zones` has been loaded before using it.